# Delete row with getParameter servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to delete a row which is printed out in my servlet. But the problem is that I have to click twice or refresh after click on the delete link. So first click gets the ID and second time I refresh the page then it deletes it. But I am pretty sure that there is a good clever way to delete this row in a single click, hope my problem is understandable.

I tried `response.setHeader()` so after I`ve clicked on the link it automatically refreshes, but it will start refrhesing continuously and it is not a good way to fix the issue, I guess.

Heres the code I am using right now.

```
    for(Customers customer : customers)
    {
        String value3 = customer.getCode();
        customer.getId();
        out.println(        
    "<tbody><tr> "      
    + "<td id='row_"+value3+"'>"+ customer.getFirst_name()+" "+"</td>"
    + "<td id='row_"+value3+"'>"+ customer.getSurname()+" "+"</td>"
    + "<td id='row_"+value3+"'>"+ customer.getCode()+" " +"</td>"
    + " "+"<td><a id='delete_"+value3+"' href='./Search?do="+value3+"'>Delete</a></td></tr>"                    
     );     

    }
    dao.deleteCustomer(request.getParameter("do"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You render your table first and then you perform the deletion. Which means that even if you delete a customer it will already be rendered in the table when the deletion happens. You must first delete the customer and then print-out the table.

On a side note, why are you performing deletion in `/Search` servlet and why are you doing it using GET request? That is not exactly a best practice.